# SQL - Average number of related records with group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by, relational-database, average

I have a table of records (lets call them TV shows) with an air_date field.

I have another table of advertisements that are related by a show_id field.

I am trying to get the average number of advertisements per show for each date (with a where clause specifying the shows).

I currently have this:

```
SELECT 
 `air_date`,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `commercial` WHERE `show_id` =  `show`.`id`) AS `num_commercials`,  
FROM `show` 
WHERE ...
```

This gives me a result like so:

```
air_date  | num_commercials
2015-6-30 | 6
2015-6-30 | 3
2015-6-30 | 8
2015-6-30 | 2
2015-6-31 | 9
2015-6-31 | 4
```

When I do a GROUP_BY, it only gives me one of the records, but I want the average for each air_date.

Comment: `2015-6-31` ? June with 31 days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure I am clear on what you want - but does this do it

```
SELECT `air_date`, 
AVG((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `commercial` WHERE `show_id` =  `show`.`id`)) AS  `num_commercials`,  
FROM `show` 
WHERE .....
GROUP BY `air_date`
```

(Note double parentheses for AVG function is required)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was missing the double parentheses.  Can't believe I spent 2 hours on this...

Comment: Caught me out too for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to select count of commercials by air_date/show, then use an outer query to select the average commercials count per air_date.

Something like this should work:

```
select air_date, avg(num_commercials)
from 
(
  select show.air_date as air_date, 
    show.id as show_id,
    count(*) as num_commercials
  from show 
    inner join commercial on commercial.show_id =  show.id
  group by show.air_date, show.id
  where ...
) sub
group by air_date
```